# Redis keyspace event not-firing

Tags: node.js, redis

I have two redis clients, in one file I have a simple script setting and deleted Redis keys:

```
var redis = require("redis");

var client = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1');
client.config("SET","notify-keyspace-events", "KEA");

client.set("string key 1", "string val", redis.print);
client.set("string key 2", "string val", redis.print);
client.set("placeholder","placeholder value", redis.print);
client.del("string key 1", redis.print);
client.del("string key", redis.print);
```

in the second file, I have a Redis client serving as a subscriber:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var subscriber = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1');

const REDIS_PUB_MESSAGE = 'redis_pub_message';
const EVENT_SET = '__keyevent@0__:set';
const EVENT_DEL = '__keyevent@0__:del';
const SPACE_SPECIFIC_KEY = '__keyspace@0__:placeholder set';
const EVENT_SPECIFIC_KEY = '__keyevent@0__:placeholder set';
const SPACE_SPECIFIC_KEY_set = '__keyspace@0__:set placeholder';
const EVENT_SPECIFIC_KEY_set = '__keyevent@0__:set placeholder';

subscriber.on('message', function(channel, key) {
    switch (channel) {
        case SPACE_SPECIFIC_KEY_set:
            console.log('space specific key channel:',channel,'key:',key);
        case EVENT_SPECIFIC_KEY_set:
            console.log('event specific key channel:',channel,'key:',key);
        case EVENT_SPECIFIC_KEY:
            console.log('space specific key channel:',channel,'key:',key);
        case SPACE_SPECIFIC_KEY:
            console.log('event specific key channel:',channel,'key:',key);
    }
});
```

the key 'placeholder' is being set, so is there any good reason that I am not getting any output in the 'message' handler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot to subscribe the subscriber client to a specific channel. Furthermore, if you want to watch for all events, you need to use pattern-based subscription.

You may want to do something like this (untested):

```
subscriber.on("pmessage", function (pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log("("+  pattern +")" + " client received message on " + channel + ": " + message);
    switch (channel) {
        // blah blah blah
        // ...
    }
});
subscriber.psubscribe(''__key*__:*')
```

See more information in the [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/notifications), and in [node_redis examples](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/tree/master/examples).

**Update:**

Here is an example to illustrate the difference between channel subcription and pattern subscription. Proper error handling is omitted for brevity sake.

```
var redis = require("redis");

var client = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1');
var subscriber1 = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1');
var subscriber2 = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1');

// First subscriber listens only to events occurring for key mykey
function S1(next) {
    subscriber1.on('message', function(channel, msg) {
        console.log( "S1: received on "+channel+" event "+msg )
    });
    subscriber1.subscribe( "__keyspace@0__:mykey", function (err) {
        next();
    });
}

// Second subscriber listens to events occuring for ALL keys
function S2(next) {
    subscriber2.on('pmessage', function(pattern,channel, msg) {
        console.log( "S2: received on "+channel+" event "+msg )
    });
    subscriber2.psubscribe( "__keyspace@0__:*", function (err) {
        next();
    });
}

// Do something with keys mykey and anotherkey
function do_something() {
    client.set("mykey","example", function( err ) {
        client.set("mykey", "another example", function( err ) {
            client.del("mykey", function( err ) {
                client.set("anotherkey","example", function( err ) {
                    client.del("anotherkey");
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

// Here we go
S1( function () {
    S2( function () {
        do_something();
    });
});
```

The result of this script is:

```
S1: received on __keyspace@0__:mykey event set
S2: received on __keyspace@0__:mykey event set
S2: received on __keyspace@0__:mykey event set
S1: received on __keyspace@0__:mykey event set
S1: received on __keyspace@0__:mykey event del
S2: received on __keyspace@0__:mykey event del
S2: received on __keyspace@0__:anotherkey event set
S2: received on __keyspace@0__:anotherkey event del
```

You can see that first subscriber received only events for mykey, while second subscriber receives events for all keys.

Comment: you're right, this is the problem. but one question about your answer - "if you want to watch for all events", I am not trying to be incredulous, but why pmessage instead of message? I currently don't see the purpose of pmessage.

Comment: Well, if you just use a simple channel based subscription, you will receive only a single type of messages, because the channel name corresponds to the message type. For instance if you subscribe to \_\_keyevent@0\_\_:del, you will only receive del events for all keys. If you need also the other events, you have to subscribe to several channels, or use pattern-based subscription.

Comment: Didier, sorry I didn't quite understand you. And in response, it looks like I am able to subscribe to a specific key, as with the line "const EVENT_SPECIFIC_KEY_del = '__keyevent@0__:del placeholder';" this listens to the key called "placeholder"...I still don't understand the purpose of pmessage vs. message. Perhaps if I understood that dichotomy I would understand what you mean.

Comment: No - you cannot subscribe to a specific key by watching a keyevent channel. You have one keyevent channel per __command__ (the key being provided as the message payload). If you need to subscribe for a specific __key__, you have to watch for a keyspace channel (in that case, the command will be provided as the message payload).

Comment: My suggestion is to use the monitor command on your Redis instance so you can see exactly the commands sent by the Node.js scripts. I suppose if you subscribe to "\_\_keyevent@\_\_0:del placeholder", the node.js driver will actually subscribe to "\_\_keyevent@\_\_0:del" and "placeholder" channels. No event will be received from "placeholder", but the delete events for __all__ keys will be received on the other one.

Comment: Regarding the difference between susbscribe/message and psubscribe/pmessage: the former allows a subscription to a given list of channels, the latter allows a subscription to a family of channels whose name is defined with a glob-style expression (i.e. with *, ?, [] characters).

Comment: Hi Didier, thanks for your help - is there way you could provide an example of how to listen for events for a specific key (like placeholder in this case)? I am having trouble finding examples of that online. I guess I could put up a new SO question and you could answer it there.

Comment: this helped, I got my example to work. Basically it was the difference between doing '__keyspace@0__:placeholder set' and '__keyspace@0__:placeholder'. the latter listened to the specific key called placeholder, the former didn't...but now the issue I just want to listen to deletes on placeholder, not all placeholder events. This is confusing to say the least.