# Redis Keyspace Notifications subscription for field&value

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, subscribe, ioredis

i'm currently working about Redis Expire Event

**My goal :** get the Value, Field to do something in next process after Data in Redis already expire

so i had found Redis Keyspace Notifications Feature
That Allow client to Subscribe to Channel in Redis to Recieve Event affecting Data in reset like Expire

so i have some example code : https://github.com/toygame/nodejs-redis-keyspace-notifications

```
subscriber.subscribe("__keyevent@0__:expired")
subscriber.on('message', async(channel, message) => {
        // do somethings
        console.log(message);       
    })
```

`Result : Key0`

And this work find but the Result i got is only Key that i have set into redis and expired

I have already do some research
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/redis-getting-notified-when-a-key-is-expired-or-changed-ca3e1f1c7f0a

but its found only Event that maybe i can get as result but not for Value, Field that i expect

is their anyway to get Those Value and Field ?

FYI. Document https://redis.io/topics/notifications

**UPDATE**
according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556450/11349357

> Keyspace notifications do not report the value, only the key's name and/or command performed are included in the published message.The main underlaying reasoning for this is that Redis values can become quite large.

> If you really really really need this kind of behavior, well that's pretty easy actually. Because keyspace notifications are using Pub/Sub messages, you can just call PUBLISH yourself after each relevant operation, and with the information that you're interested in.

look like i can't use this Redis Keyspace but i have to publish its on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RedisGears](https://oss.redis.com/redisgears) to process keyspace notification and get both key and value.

You can write your processing code in python and register it in Redis.
e.g. Capture each keyspace event and store to a Stream

```py
GearsBuilder() \
.foreach(lambda x: execute('XADD', "notifications-stream", '*', *sum([[k,v] for k,v in x.items()],[]))) \
.register(prefix="person:*", eventTypes=['hset', 'hmset'], mode='sync')
```

You can read more about this example here: https://oss.redis.com/redisgears/examples.html#reliable-keyspace-notification

Comment: Now i'm using Keyspace notification  concern about deplicate Key when using subscription is that RedisGears might solve that problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate key?

Comment: i'm currently using Redis Keyspace Notification to publish expired key  when it got expire  then subscribe on another side  
so it's will be 1 key as output

so the thing i concern is when We do Horizontal scaling 
Subscribe will got scaling  and it's gonna be like  10 subscribes  and then i got 10 Keys as result

Comment: If you reigster on a single key with Gears then you'll only get one Exipre event.